# Cryptic Errors. Probably a quick fix? ( noob )

Tags: math-mode

Completely confused. Tried to run latex script from yesterday on a different computer. Doesn't work now. here are my errors:

```
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.118     }
           ]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{e
quation.1.3}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.125     }
           pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{eq
uation.1.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.125     }
           pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{eq
uation.1.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.125     }
           pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{eq
uation.1.4}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.144     }
           pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{eq
uation.1.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.144     }
           pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{eq
uation.1.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.144     }

Overfull \hbox (8.95819pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 157--158
[]\OT1/lmr/m/n/10.95 Signal de-cay dis-tur-bances are char-ac-ter-ized by the p
er-tur-ba-tion of the nom-i-nal wave-form sig-nal, $\OML/lmm/m/it/10.95 v[]\OT1
/lmr/m/n/10.95 (\OML/lmm/m/it/10.95 t\OT1/lmr/m/n/10.95 )$,
[3pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation.1.
2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.159 ..._{perturbed}(t) = v_{nominal}(1 + d(t))$$
                                                  pdfTeX warning (ext4): destin
ation with the same identifier (name{equation.1.1}) has been already used, dupl
icate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.159 ..._{perturbed}(t) = v_{nominal}(1 + d(t))$$
                                                  pdfTeX warning (ext4): destin
ation with the same identifier (name{equation.1.2}) has been already used, dupl
icate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.159 ..._{perturbed}(t) = v_{nominal}(1 + d(t))$$
                                                  pdfTeX warning (ext4): destin
ation with the same identifier (name{equation.1.3}) has been already used, dupl
icate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.159 ..._{perturbed}(t) = v_{nominal}(1 + d(t))$$
                                                  pdfTeX warning (ext4): destin
ation with the same identifier (name{equation.1.4}) has been already used, dupl
icate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.159 ..._{perturbed}(t) = v_{nominal}(1 + d(t))$$
                                                  ]

! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.171 ...\begin{tabular}{ | m | m | m | m{5cm} | }

? 
Process interrupted by user
```

Any ideas? Here is the code at line 118.

```
 \equations{
        d(t) &=    \lbrace \hat x \ast h \rbrace(t) \\
             &=    \lbrace x + n \ast h \rbrace(t) \\
             &=    \lbrace x \ast h \rbrace(t) + \lbrace n \ast h \rbrace (t)\\
             &:=    d_x(t) + d_n(t).\\
    }
```

where equations is a macro for:

```
\newcommand{\equations}[1]{ \begin{subequations} 
                                \begin{align}                                 
                                    #1 
                                \end{align}
                            \end{subequations} }
```

For reference, here are the included packages

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}    % font definition
\usepackage{amsmath}    % math fonts
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu}           % tables, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables
```

Windows 7, x32 texWorks version. Also, I have used latex "successfully" a number of times ( to the point of finishing the project ) but I have almost willfully avoided learning latex; for short term success, it seemed quicker to hack latex than actually learn it. But now that I'm actually trying to learn it, I feel stupid and lost and confused, and I'm going slower than when trying to hack it. It's quite possible due to my incompetency that I'm lacking some details.

Also, what typeset settings should I be using? LaTeX isn't even an option for some reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `\deq`? Apart from that, your fragment compiles normally for me. Could you try tp upload a Minimal (non-)Working Example?

Comment: that may have been a spelling error, I deleted it though now, and I still get the same errors, I'll update the post.

Comment: Err... I copied and pasted the original *.tex file into another to make the minimal working example, but without changing anything, it successfully converted to pdf!!! what does that mean?!

Comment: ?? There can be so many reasons, it's impossible to say without the code. It may be a simple missing bracket, a typo in a command…

Comment: @Bernard Not if it is simply copy-pasted from the original ;). OP: What you've posted are warnings - not errors. They would not, I think, cause a failure to compile to PDF. (Although they would probably mean your hyperlinks are screwed up.) Try deleting all generated files from the original and compiling again. (Generated files are things like `.aux, .log, .toc, .bcf, .bbl, .ind, .nav, .snm, ...` - which you have depends on the document you are compiling though `.log` and `.aux` are always there.

Comment: You are using the `hyperref` package, which should be loaded last (for exceptions see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/15925).  Loading it earlier gives your posted.